what is the value of $e^{jx}$ as $x \to\infty?$
This came up when we started Fourier Transform in class but the teacher essentially handwaved it to be equal to zero.
if I were to treat the power as real then it obviously tends to zero
using the Euler expansion however, I am almost certain that it is undefined. but bounded (kind of like $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sin x$)
This exponential comes often enough that i have to know about this.
Btw, if anyone is interested, the specific question it was first used in was $$FT(u(t))=\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(t)e^{-jwt}$$
this resolves to $$\frac{e^{-jw\infty}-1}{-jw}=-\frac{1}{jw}$$
if any of you have a less... mathematically painful way to evaluate it, please do tell.

Is $j=\sqrt{-1},$ the imaginary unit? It definitely doesn't go to zero then.

You really have to do some hand-wavy things with some Fourier transforms until you reach functional analysis and realize that the transform is really being applied to distributions, not functions. The Dirac $\delta$ function, for example, is not really a function, but a distribution.

What is $u(t)$ defined to be for the "specific example?"

@ThomasAndrews yes  j^2=-1
and u(t)=0 fot t<0 and =1 for t=>1

@ThomasAndrews so, what i said in the third line is correct? $e^{-j \infty}$ is indeterminate but bounded?

It is hand waving. The Fourier transform is defined for integrable functions, and the unit step is not integrable. From an engineering standpoint, one can apply a few rules to obtain useful results, but these are based on the mathematics of distributions.

basically, you're asking what's the FT of the Heaviside function, right?

There is no limit of $e^{j \omega t}$ as $t \to \infty$ if $\omega \neq 0$.

@SineoftheTime yep

@copper.hat i see. so, if it appears again, i cant just take the exponential to be zero? bummer.
also, did what i said in third line correct? or is it that it the exponential $e^{-jw\infty}$ is literally undefined like 1/0?

@AnimeshShukla It is undefined, it is like looking for a limit as a a point spins around in a circle.

Yes, the limit is undefined and the function is bounded.

https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Fourier+transform+Heaviside

i guess it answers the question. and now i feel kinda dumb.  should i delete the question?

It is a reasonable question, and good that you are curious.

alright imma keep it up.

Please put the definition of $u$ in your question. As written, the question is incomplete, and a reader should not have to dig through comments to know the question.@AnimeshShukla

See THIS ANSWER
